# Is there a way to make the Splitter resize immediately on drag, instead of waiting for mouse up?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a way to make the Splitter resize instantly when the mouse drags. By default it shows an ugly dot pattern preview and doesn't show you what the resize will actually look like until you let go.

I've seen this immediate resize behaviour in Outlook, for instance. Does the .NET Framework provide a way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have apparently customized the behaviour of the splitter container in my project.
But you are welcome to the code :

```
class RibbonSplitContainer : SplitContainer
{
    private Color topGradientColor = Color.FromArgb(89, 135, 214);
    private Color bottomGradientColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 45, 150);
    private Color notchColor = Color.FromArgb(40, 50, 71);
    private Color notchShadowColor = Color.FromArgb(249, 249, 251);
    private Color notchTouchColor = Color.FromArgb(97, 116, 152);
    private ushort nbrNotches = 9;
    private int diff = 0;
    private bool drawBorderBottom = false;
    private bool drawBorderTop = false;
    private bool drawBorderLeft = false;
    private bool drawBorderRight = false;

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "89,135,214")]
    [CategoryAttribute("Appearance")]
    public Color TopGradientColor
    {
        get { return topGradientColor; }
        set { topGradientColor = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0,45,150")]
    public Color BottomGradientColor
    {
        get { return bottomGradientColor; }
        set { bottomGradientColor = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "40, 50, 71")]
    public Color NotchColor
    {
        get { return notchColor; }
        set { notchColor = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "249, 249, 251")]
    public Color NotchShadowColor
    {
        get { return notchShadowColor; }
        set { notchShadowColor = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "97, 116, 152")]
    public Color NotchTouchColor
    {
        get { return notchTouchColor; }
        set { notchTouchColor = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(9)]
    public ushort NbrNotches
    {
        get { return nbrNotches; }
        set { nbrNotches = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [CategoryAttribute("Appearance")]
    public bool DrawBorderBottom
    {
        get { return drawBorderBottom; }
        set { drawBorderBottom = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [CategoryAttribute("Appearance")]
    public bool DrawBorderTop
    {
        get { return drawBorderTop; }
        set { drawBorderTop = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [CategoryAttribute("Appearance")]
    public bool DrawBorderLeft
    {
        get { return drawBorderLeft; }
        set { drawBorderLeft = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [CategoryAttribute("Appearance")]
    public bool DrawBorderRight
    {
        get { return drawBorderRight; }
        set { drawBorderRight = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
                int y = e.Y - diff;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;
                SplitterDistance = y;
            }
            else
            {
                int x = e.X - diff;
                if (x < 0) x = 0;
                SplitterDistance = x;
            }
            Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
            Paint(g);
            g.Dispose();
            this.Panel1.Invalidate();
            this.Panel2.Invalidate();
            Update();
        }
        else base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            diff = e.Y - this.Panel1.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            diff = e.X - this.Panel1.Width;
        }
    }

    protected new virtual void Paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Rectangle r = ClientRectangle;

        if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            r.Y = this.Panel1.Height;
            r.Height = this.SplitterWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            r.X = this.Panel1.Width;
            r.Width = this.SplitterWidth;
        }

        LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(r, topGradientColor,
            bottomGradientColor, (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) ? LinearGradientMode.Vertical : LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
        g.FillRectangle(brush, r);
        Pen pen = new Pen(bottomGradientColor);
        if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) g.DrawLine(pen, 0, r.Height, r.Width, r.Height);
        else g.DrawLine(pen, r.Width, 0, r.Width, r.Height);

        int startx;
        int starty;
        if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            startx = (Width - (4 * NbrNotches - 1)) / 2;
            starty = r.Y + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            startx = r.X + 2;
            starty = (Height - (4 * NbrNotches - 1)) / 2;
        }

        for (ushort i = 0; i < NbrNotches; i++)
        {
            pen.Color = notchColor;
            g.DrawPolygon(pen, new Point[] { new Point(startx, starty + 1), new Point(startx, starty), new Point(startx + 1, starty) });
            pen.Color = notchTouchColor;
            g.DrawLine(pen, startx + 1, starty + 1, startx + 2, starty + 1);
            pen.Color = notchShadowColor;
            g.DrawPolygon(pen, new Point[] { new Point(startx + 1, starty + 2), new Point(startx + 2, starty + 2), new Point(startx + 2, starty + 1) });

            if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) startx += 4;
            else starty += 4;
        }

        brush.Dispose();
        pen.Dispose();

        if (drawBorderBottom)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, r.Left, r.Bottom-1, r.Right, r.Bottom-1);
        }

        if (drawBorderTop)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Top);
        }

        if (drawBorderLeft)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, r.Left, r.Top, r.Left, r.Bottom);
        }

        if (drawBorderRight)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, r.Right-1, r.Top, r.Right-1, r.Bottom);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Paint(g);
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

It gives the splitter a whole new look too.

Comment: I am looking at the properties I have, because mine has the behavior you want.

Comment: Updated my answer and decided to post my custom splitter code.

Comment: That's an important elaboration over the first edit. As I thought the standard panel does not allow such behaviour - you had to repaint the panels manually. Still, excellent working solution, so +1.

Comment: One important subtlety I see with your code- you need to track mouse up/down and check it in `OnMouseMove`. It's not enough to check whether the button is down in `OnMouseMove`, because clicking *outside* the splitter and dragging across the splitter will cause the splitter to move. You need to be sure the initial mouse down was located inside the splitter. Looks nice though. If you fix this I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I tried what you describe here and I cannot get that behavior. I think standard mousedown does a mousecapture so you don't get mousemoves from something that was clicked somewhere  else. I put a breakpoint in the mousemove right after the button check, I don't get there if the mousedown was somewhere else. So the code is fine, I think.

Comment: Oh, you are right and I am wrong. I'm sorry. Great answer!